# installation of another version of Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, installation-package

I have the numpy version 1.16.1 but I need to install 1.15.4 because pyinstaller does not work. do I have to uninstall the current version or can I install version 1.15.4 directly?

Comment: You could create another python environment through virtual environments or conda environments

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
pip install numpy==1.15.4
```

Comment: I have to install via tar.gz or .whl packages

Answer (score 5):

You will need to do

`pip install numpy==1.15.4` directly but it will uninstall current numpy installation, if you don't want to do that, you should use virtualenv.

`pip install virtualenv`

and then in your virtualenv install the version of numpy without medelling with your working installations so you don't accidentally break anything.

**Edit**
Since OP said that they want to install it from whl file
`pip install --upgrade <filename>` type the filename **without** the angular brackets.

Comment: I have to install via tar.gz or .whl packages

Answer (score 5):

upgrade can downgrade also so you can try this:-
    pip install --upgrade numpy==1.15.4

Anyway, it is preferred to uninstall the existing one then :

```
pip install --upgrade numpy==1.15.4
```

Comment: I have to install via tar.gz or .whl packages

Comment: Then try  :-- pip install numpy-1.15.4+mkl-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl

Comment: in fact I wanted to do this. only the versions of python and numpy are different

Comment: Can you elaborate a little ?